If this is the answer, what is the question?
This is a philosophical riddle in the spirit of other self-referential sentences which may be “paradoxes” (or not), like the liar’s paradox.
If this is the answer, what is the question?

can you expand on why it is a riddle at all? aside from being seemingly incoherent (which I wouldn't even charge the Liar with)

What, like Marco responded it maybe possible that the question is open ended and infinitely many possibilities. Again the use of the word "this" is too vague hence the infinite potential for answers. What is "this" (referring to)? - this could also be the question.

If that was the answer, then this must be the question.

This? Hmmmmmmmm

The question is, "What is the question?"
Alternatively, possibly "What?"
